# Git error about non fast forwarded changes to branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

Right now I have a repo called playGround
It has 3 commits recorded
My local copy of playGround is behind 1 commit
I also have a branch called SecondB which was copied from my local copy of playGround. Then on SecondB I made two changes so SecondB has a total of 4 commits to it.

git remote show origin:

```
HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    SecondB tracked
    master  tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    SecondB merges with remote SecondB
    master  merges with remote master
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    SecondB pushes to SecondB (up to date)
    master  pushes to master  (local out of date)
```

My question is when I am on the SecondB branch and try to push it will give me this error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'url for repo'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

unless I specify what to push to like : `git push origin SecondB` while I am on SecondB

How come I cannot simply do `git push` as I am on SecondB and have it push to the remote copy of SecondB?

OKAY NEW INFORMATION:
Upon examining the errors further it seems that every time I try to git push it tries to push to the remote branch AND the remote MASTER. Why is this behavior happening? and how would I fix this?

Comment: There is likely commits in the remote you need to fetch/merge or pull before you can push. Can you check what `git fetch` and then `git status` says?

Comment: git fetch does nothing  
git status just says:  
# On branch SecondB  
nothing to commit (working directory clean)  
Edit: hit enter too fast

Comment: [jthill's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43021075/1256452) is the right one but the precise options for `push.default` depend on your Git version. What version of Git are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `git push` without other parameters, it tries to push all the local branches that are tracking a remote branch. In your example it's `master` and `SecondB`. But your local `master` is behind the remote `master`, so it cannot be pushed. That's why the command fails.

You can only push with `git push` if all tracking branches are ahead or in sync with their remote counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Change push's default behavior with the [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault) config setting.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't merged the local branch you are trying to push with the *current* content of the remote branch you are trying to push into. In this case git is trying to get you to merge it before you push. Normally you would fetch/merge (or pull) then you would be able to push without problems. If you want to forget about that revision that you don't have and make the remote have the branch as you have it locally, you could use `git push -f`

Comment: But I have no changes on the remote branch that is not already on the local  copy of that branch

Comment: so, if you say: ```git fetch the-remote; git branch --contains the-remote/remote-branch-name```, you get your local branch on the report of the git branch call?